# Laptop can't ping (or see on arp) network printer. All other devices can

Tags: networking, router, windows-10, printer, tcpip

I have a small home office network. Two laptops connecting to the router wirelessly and the printer (Sharp MX2301N) is connected to the router by ethernet cable.

The Faulty Computer (FC), running Windows 10, cannot connect to the printer, cannot ping it, cannot see it on the arp list. The OK Computer (OCC) (also a Windows 10 laptop) CAN connect, ping and see it on arp.

I have removed and updated all printer drivers, cleared all print server ports, flushed and renewed the DNS and so on. Occasionally my efforts mean that I briefly 'see' the printer's IP in the arp -a list but the moment I try to ping it, it disappears!

The printer's IP is fixed as

```
192.168.0.23
```

The default gateway is

```
192.168.0.1
```

The subnet mask is

```
255.255.255.0
```

Here is the results of arp -a from FC (Faulty Computer) which has the IP 192.168.0.12

```
Interface: 192.168.0.12 --- 0x3
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.0.1           c0-3e-0f-3e-b8-08     dynamic
192.168.0.3           70-18-8b-f3-9f-35     dynamic
192.168.0.6           60-02-b4-fd-5c-1e     dynamic
192.168.0.9           a0-f3-c1-eb-a2-37     dynamic
192.168.0.11          90-8d-6c-b6-f2-f5     dynamic
192.168.0.41          18-0c-ac-fb-6e-00     dynamic
192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

As you can see, the 192.168.0.23 is missing... but it appears fine when I run arp -a from any other laptop connecting to the wi-fi network.

I should also say, the printer is unable to ping back to FC either. But it can ping OK Computer fine.

I have tried the printer on another IP address. I have also tried FC on a different IP address. No difference.

FIREWALL: I have tried turning off Windows Firewall - no change. I don't have any other firewall/AV software.

Here is the ipconfig for Faulty Computer:

```
C:\Users\David>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd21:fada:6983:0:3088:7815:ca14:3a29
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd21:fada:6983:0:4dd6:8e6e:ae5b:3814
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3088:7815:ca14:3a29%3
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.12
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:1032:1d67:a8ae:69c5
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1032:1d67:a8ae:69c5%11
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.Home:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
```

I've deleted any reference to Sharp printer from the registry.
My hosts files don't have anything in them.

I cannot understand why my computer cannot see the printer!

I have searched the internet high and low and have not found anyone with this problem but this site has good, helpful answers to similar questions so I am hoping that someone can assist me.

Comment: Did you try - "Add a static Arp entry for frequent accessed hosts "?
      `ARP -s ip_addr eth_addr [if_addr]`. See http://ss64.com/nt/arp.html